# Delete large data with same partition key from DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, delete-operator

I have DynamoDB table structured like this

```
A   B    C    D
1   id1  foo hi
1   id2  var hello
```

`A` is the partition key and `B` is the sort key.

Let' say I only have the partition key and don't know the sort key and I'd like to delete all entries have the same partition key.

So I am thinking about loading entries by query with a fixed size (e.g 1000) and delete them in a batch until there are no more entries with the partition key left in DynamoDB.

Is it possible to delete entries without loading them first?

Comment: The same question and a code example https://stackoverflow.com/a/16552620/8769801

Comment: is there a way to delete items with only hash key (without range key)?

Comment: No. That is a surely missing feature. Hopefully in the future.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteItem.html

### DeleteItem

> Deletes a single item in a table by primary key.
>
> For the primary key, you must provide all of the attributes. For
> example, with a simple primary key, you only need to provide a value
> for the partition key. For a composite primary key, you must provide
> values for both the partition key and the sort key.

In order to delete an item you must provide the whole primary key (partition + sort key). So in your case you would need to query on the partition key, get all of the primary keys, then use those to delete each item. You can also use BatchWriteItem

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html

### BatchWriteItem

> The BatchWriteItem operation puts or deletes multiple items in one or
> more tables. A single call to BatchWriteItem can write up to 16 MB of
> data, which can comprise as many as 25 put or delete requests.
> Individual items to be written can be as large as 400 KB.
>
> **DeleteRequest** - Perform a DeleteItem operation on the specified item. The item to be deleted is identified by a Key subelement: Key -
> A map of primary key attribute values that uniquely identify the item.
> Each entry in this map consists of an attribute name and an attribute
> value. For each primary key, you must provide all of the key
> attributes. For example, with a simple primary key, you only need to
> provide a value for the partition key. **For a composite primary key,
> you must provide values for both the partition key and the sort key**.

Comment: so the answer is no. For a composite primary key - there is no way to delete items with only hash (partition) key

Comment: @codereviewanskquestions this problem is usually designed by doing a `begins_with="id"` on the range key

Answer (score 11):

No, but you can Query all the items for the partition, and then issue an individual DeleteRequest for each item, which you can batch in multiple BatchWrite calls of up to 25 items.

**JS code**

```js
async function deleteItems(tableName, partitionId ) {
  
  const queryParams = {
    TableName: tableName,
    KeyConditionExpression: 'partitionId = :partitionId',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: { ':partitionId': partitionId } ,
  };

  const queryResults = await docClient.query(queryParams).promise()
  if (queryResults.Items && queryResults.Items.length > 0) {
    
    const batchCalls = chunks(queryResults.Items, 25).map( async (chunk) => {
      const deleteRequests = chunk.map( item => {
        return {
          DeleteRequest : {
            Key : {
              'partitionId' : item.partitionId,
              'sortId' : item.sortId,

            }
          }
        }
      })

      const batchWriteParams = {
        RequestItems : {
          [tableName] : deleteRequests
        }
      }
      await docClient.batchWrite(batchWriteParams).promise()
    })

    await Promise.all(batchCalls)
  }
}

// https://stackoverflow.com/a/37826698/3221253
function chunks(inputArray, perChunk) {
  return inputArray.reduce((all,one,i) => {
    const ch = Math.floor(i/perChunk); 
    all[ch] = [].concat((all[ch]||[]),one); 
    return all
 }, [])
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For production databases and critical Amazon DynamoDB tables, recommendation is to use batch-write-item to purge huge data.

batch-write-item (with DeleteRequest) is 10 to 15 times faster than delete-item.

```
aws dynamodb scan --table-name "test_table_name" --projection-expression "primary_key, timestamp" --filter-expression "timestamp < :oldest_date" --expression-attribute-values '{":oldest_date":{"S":"2020-02-01"}}' --max-items 25 --total-segments "$TOTAL_SEGMENT" --segment "$SEGMENT_NUMBER" > $SCAN_OUTPUT_FILE

cat $SCAN_OUTPUT_FILE | jq -r ".Items[] | tojson" | awk '{ print "{\"DeleteRequest\": {\"Key\": " $0 " }}," }' | sed '$ s/.$//' | sed '1 i { "test_table_name": [' | sed '$ a ] }' > $INPUT_FILE

aws dynamodb batch-write-item --request-items file://$INPUT_FILE
```

Please find more information @ https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-delete-huge-data-from-dynamodb-table-f3be586c011c